# Subset of points in noetherian scheme of rank $\le n$ is open

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf over a Noetherian scheme $X$. Lets define its rank in a point $x \in X$ as the dimension of $\mathcal{F}_x \otimes k(x)$ (here $k(x)$ is the residue field in $x$). How can one show that the set of points in which rank is less or equal to $n$ is open?

It seems to be something geometrically intuitive but I am lost about rigorous proof.

Comment: One keyword here is "upper semicontinuity", by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider n-th external power of your sheaf. Since we are working not over a field of characteristic zero, it is has to be defined as quotient of tensor power rather than subspace in tensor power. It is easy to check that external power respect base change. Therefore I reduce your problem to case $n=0$.

In this case, this is standard statement that support of coherent sheaf is closed.

Comment: One can also argue without $\bigwedge$: if you have germs generating the fiber at a point $P$, lift those to honest sections in some neighborhood, and in that neighborhood look at the cokernel of $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus r} \to \mathcal{F}$. The support of it is closed and doesn't contain $P$. Of course I'm using Nakayama at least once here.